# Filter out app sites from search results

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search

On a standard SharePoint 2013 search results page, I have a simple search query of "contentclass:STS_Web Path:{SiteCollection.URL}" configured in the Search Results web part.  This query is returning only sites in the current site collection, and so it's doing exactly what it should do.

However, that includes all content sites as well as all app sites.  I'd like to modify this query to exclude the app sites and only include the content sites.  Is this possible?

Comment: Try placing an `AND` condition like `NOT Site:http://SiteURL/*` This will exclude all sites under `SiteURL`

Comment: That's not what I want to do.  I want to include all sites except for app sites.